# Packaging application on windows 8 RTM

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have just download and installed newest windows 8 version - rtm. While building package (build & run works great) I have encountered some problems. I must mention that on previous version - windows 8 RP packaging worked great.

```
Error   1   In the app manifest, the value of element OSMinVersion ('6.2.0') must have a value of '6.2.1' or higher. [..]\Package.appxmanifest
```

At first manifest file looked like that:

```
<Prerequisites>
  <OSMinVersion>6.2.0</OSMinVersion>
  <OSMaxVersionTested>6.2.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
</Prerequisites>
```

But I have changed it and still VS doesn't want to build package (the error message is still exactly the same) :/ I have tried changing it to 6.2.1 or 6.3.0 - still nothing.

Thanks for help in advance :)

PS: I have restarted IDE and even clean project - still not working.

Comment: Did you blow away bin & bld in your project directory? Is it picking up the right manifest - rg validate is looking on the right place.

Comment: @Dominic in /Bin was another Manifest file. Deleting whole folder helped ;) Thank you :)